# Kafka running on different servers?

Tags: c#, apache-kafka

I have a kafka server running on a server xx.xx.xx.xx:9092. And i have a producer console application build in C# running on different server. Is there need to install java on the server where console application is running?

Comment: No. Since you have client in C#, it uses .Net architecture for communication with your kafka server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you don’t need to install Java on a client machine unless you are using the Java client (or another JVM based client language like Scala).